# How to setup two different configurations for two listenaddresses in sshd

Tags: linux, networking, sshd

I have the following setup: a Linux machine has two IP addresses (primary and secondary) on the same network. One receives requests NAT forwarded from outside by the router/modem, the other one receives requests from the internal network only.

I would like sshd to listen from both addresses, but allow password authentication only from the internal-facing IP.

Is there any way to do that with a single ssh daemon or do I need two, each listening to a different IP?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/542327

Comment: Could you detail the 2 addresses bound to the same network ? Generally, each network is bound to a network interface to one unique address. Do you use address aliases ?

Comment: @frederic: to be honest I only found out a week ago. You can assign a number of secondary IPs to an interface. Routing would go through the primary one by default, but you can add specific routes for the secondary ones.